# https://freelancehunt.com/ - как сайт определяет пользователя?

Tags: веб-программирование, ip-address, mac-address

https://freelancehunt.com/ - как сайт определяет пользователя? То есть понимает что он это он и что пользователь не использует несколько аккаунтов?
IP, Mac-address, эл. отпечаток браузера - что ещё? Как замаскироваться и использовать несколько аккаунтов одновременно/поочередно? Тор-браузер не подходит, так как при регистрации выдает какую-то ошибку - скорее всего защита от тора.

Comment: Куки, etag, кеш ssl-сессий и еще десяток разных методов. Плюс к этому анализ поведения

Comment: Неужели нельзя скрыть свою личность и сделать куча аккаунтов?